# How can i block or avoid popup in webview?

Tags: android, webview, popup

the webpage have some popup ads is there any way to prevent the popup from loading when the popup loads the main site doesnt appears is there any way to load the main page with out popups and how can i add a download handler l mean the webview should support downloading .torrent file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private LinearLayout layoutProgress;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        layoutProgress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutProgress);
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }
            public void but(View v){

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
        });
        if(isOnline()) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://testsite.com/");
        } else {
            String summary = "<html><body><font color='red'>No Internet Connection</font></body></html>";
            webView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
            toast("No Internet Connection.");
        }
    }
    private void toast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
    }
    public void but(View v){

        webView.loadUrl("http://testsite.com/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the url changes then use shouldOverrideUrlLoading with some regex

so

```
List<String> validUrls = new LinkedList<>();
validUrls.add("https://www\\.google\\.com/*");
validUrls.add("https://www\\.facebook\\.com/*");


@Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (isValidUrl(url)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
    for (String validUrl : validUrls) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(validUrl, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

would match against any www.google.com or facebook.com urls

Comment: its not working tried it it dont even loads the hyper links tried it with your own google.com code but it also loads youtube and facebook @Matthew Shearer

Comment: how about with true/false switched?

Comment: i think after switching it worked let me test it properly

Comment: great.   docs say "     * @return True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView
     *         and handle the url itself, otherwise return false."

Comment: it works and can i give one more link with it? the view should allow two urls is it possible

Comment: alright, updated to allow adding as many regex entries as you want.

Comment: can u help me to add admob in the bottom of this webview

Comment: i think you need to give it a go and post another question if you run into any trouble.

Comment: its on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817601/how-to-add-admob-with-webview

Comment: can you please select this answer as the correct answer.  I'll take a look at the next when i get some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the urls that are opened from the webview, I don't know if it would work with the popup:

```
    WebViewClient client= new WebViewClient(){
        @Override 
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url){
           if (url.equals("popupURL"){ 
                return true; 
           }
            return false;
        } 
    } 

webView.setWebViewClient(client);
```

Comment: it changes time to time

Comment: You can check if the url contains a certain pattern. You have basically two options, look for the pattern of the popup or look for the pattern of your torrent urls. You have to return true when you don't want the url to be opened by the browser, false otherwise.

Comment: Hello @JúliaGarrigós I want to try this out, which section should I use this code?